# Android NullPointerException for passing parameter from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parameters, nullpointerexception

My app starts from `activity1`, then jumps to `activity2`, where I get the value of a String, and jump back to `activity1`. The problem is, when I try to pass the String value back, I've got `NullPointerException` error in `activity1` for getting the data value. I debugged to find the data value is correct in `activity2`. Please help me to set some flags to distinguish the initial launch of the app in `activity1` and second time jumped back to it from `activiy2`. Thanks a lot!

```
String data = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("data"); 
if(data != null){
   Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
   Toast.makeText(this, "no data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Do you use startactivityforresult?

Comment: How do you pass between activities? Can u past your code? Maybe in activity2 when you get the intents data it is not named as data.

Comment: I just fixed the problem, should check if the getExtras() got the parameter, not the data. sorry for the silly mistake, and thanks guys! Bundle infor = getIntent().getExtras();               
                if(infor != null){
                 String data = infor.getString("data");}

Comment: actually, I used simple code to start a new activity as bellow, will try the startactivityforresult. thanks! Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);       
       myIntent.putExtra("data",output);   
       activity1.this.startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

You have to start activity B with startActivityForResult method and implement onActivityResult in Activity A.